# problem with spanish characters in android app

Tags: android, character-encoding, inputstream, decoding

I have issue with spanish characters in java string. I have a content RSS feed and when i try to transform it to java object using InputStreamReader, I get outputs like "cÃ³mo" which should be "cómo". This is happening with other spanish characters like

á = Ã¡ é = Ã© í = Ã­ ó = Ã³ ú = Ãº

and more..

How can I convert these characters to proper spanish characters?

Here is how my InputStreamReader looks like:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 1024);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Got a solution you can share?

Answer (score 0):

**if you are seeing this characters in the LogCat does not support UTF-8. =)**

or change your buffer size maybe using ::

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 4*1024);
```

Comment: Why would that matter? I tried anyway. Didn't work. Spanish characters are still bad.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In my case I was reading a .txt file from a website, which was encoded in Ansi.

```
Reader reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("windows-1252")));
```